# TCP SYN RAW socket receive packet error 10022

Tags: c++, networking, tcp, winsock, winsock2

I'm porting my program from Unix to Windows, and I have a problem with the `recvfrom()` function to accept a packet. I haven't written anything with Winsock until now. I think I've done everything, according to the manual.

Also, as I read from the manual, a TCP RAW socket does not need binding via `bind()`, but it still doesn't work.

```cpp
#define NESCA

int
ncread(const char* dest_ip, int recv_timeout_ms, unsigned char **buffer, bool debug,
      int dest_port, int source_port, bool packet_trace)
{
    /*Create a structure and pass the recipient's IP into it.*/
    struct in_addr dest; dest.s_addr = inet_addr(dest_ip);

    /*Time buffer.*/
    unsigned char *read_buffer = *buffer;

    WSADATA wsaData;
    int iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != NO_ERROR) {
        wprintf(L"WSAStartup failed with error %d\n", iResult);
        return -1;
    }
    int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (sock == -1) {return SOCKET_ERROR;}

#ifdef NESCA
    /*Function similar to the entry below*/
    int result = set_socket_timeout(sock, recv_timeout_ms, 1, 1);
#else
    struct timeval timeout;
    timeout.tv_sec = recv_timeout_ms / 1000;
    timeout.tv_usec = (recv_timeout_ms % 1000) * 1000;
    int result = setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (const char*)&timeout, sizeof(timeout));
#endif
    if (result < 0)
    {
        std::cout << "timeout infinity\n\n";
        /*Timeout.*/
        fuck_fd(sock);
        return -1;
    }


    /*To compare the IPs.*/
    struct sockaddr saddr;
    int saddr_size = sizeof(saddr);
    auto start_time = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

    /*An endless loop, on accepting any packets from the system at all.*/
    for (;;)
    {
       /*Receive packet to buffer.*/
       int data_size = recvfrom(sock, (char*)read_buffer, READ_BUFFER_SIZE, 0, (sockaddr*)&saddr,
       if (data_size == -1)
       {
            /*ERROR: 10022*/
            wprintf(L"recvfrom failed with error %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            fuck_fd(sock);
            return READ_ERROR;
       }

       /*Obtaining the IP header of the received packet.*/
       struct ip_header *iph = (struct ip_header*)read_buffer;
       unsigned short iphdrlen = (iph->ihl) * 4;
       if (iphdrlen < 20)
       {
          fuck_fd(sock);
          return IP_HEADER_LEN_ERROR;
       }

       /*Retrieve the sender's IP from it.*/
       struct sockaddr_in source;
       memset(&source, 0, sizeof(source));
       source.sin_addr.s_addr = iph->saddr;

       /*Compare the IP to see if it matches the one we sent it to.
        * This is to discard other packets.*/
       if (source.sin_addr.s_addr != dest.s_addr)
       {
          if (debug) {std::cout << "Got the wrong package.\n";}

          /*A windowless for timeout might work here.*/
          auto current_time = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
          auto elapsed_time = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(current_time - start_time).count();
          if (elapsed_time >= recv_timeout_ms)
          {
                  std::cout << "timeout infinity\n\n";
             fuck_fd(sock);
             return INFINITY_TIMEOUT_EXITED;
          }

          /*If it's the wrong one, it catches again until it times out,
           * on a windowless loop. Or until the right packet arrives.*/
          continue;
       }
       else 
       {
#ifdef NESCA
          if (packet_trace)
          {
            struct in_addr addr;
            addr.s_addr = iph->saddr;
            std::string source_ip = inet_ntoa(addr);
            addr.s_addr = iph->daddr;
            std::string dest_ip = inet_ntoa(addr);

            struct tcp_header *tcph = (struct tcp_header*)(buffer+ iphdrlen);
            unsigned short id = ntohs(iph->id);
            unsigned int seq = ntohl(tcph->seq);
            unsigned int iplen = ntohs(iph->tot_len);
            packet_trace1.lock();
            np3.nlog_packet_trace("RCVD", "TCP", source_ip, dest_ip, dest_port,               source_port, "", iph->ttl, id, tcph->window, seq, iplen);
            packet_trace1.unlock();
          }
#endif
          /*If it's the right packet.
           * Fill the buffer with it.*/
          *buffer = read_buffer;
          fuck_fd(sock);
          return SUCCESS_READ;
       }
    }
    /*oh.*/
    fuck_fd(sock);
    return READ_ERROR;
}
```

**Close sock function:**

```cpp
int fuck_fd(int fd)
{
#ifdef _WIN32
    WSACleanup();
    closesocket(fd);
#else
    close(fd);
#endif
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error 10022 is [`WSAEINVAL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/WinSock/windows-sockets-error-codes-2):

> | Return code/value | Description |
> | --- | --- |
> | WSAEINVAL 10022 | Invalid argument. Some invalid argument was supplied (for example, specifying an invalid level to the [setsockopt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winsock/nf-winsock-setsockopt) function). In some instances, it also refers to the current state of the socket — for instance, calling [accept](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Winsock2/nf-winsock2-accept) on a socket that is not listening. |

Per Microsoft's [`recvfrom()` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-recvfrom):

> If no error occurs, recvfrom returns the number of bytes received. If the connection has been gracefully closed, the return value is zero. Otherwise, a value of SOCKET_ERROR is returned, and a specific error code can be retrieved by calling [WSAGetLastError](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winsock/nf-winsock-wsagetlasterror).
>
> | Error code | Meaning |
> | --- | --- |
> | [WSAEINVAL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/WinSock/windows-sockets-error-codes-2) | The socket has not been bound with [bind](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winsock/nf-winsock-bind), or an unknown flag was specified, or MSG_OOB was specified for a socket with SO_OOBINLINE enabled, or (for byte stream-style sockets only) len was zero or negative. |

We can rule out the flags, since you are not using any.

And, we can probably rule out the `len` parameter, assuming `READ_BUFFER_SIZE` is a positive value, and that your `buffer` really does point to a valid memory block of at least `READ_BUFFER_SIZE` bytes in size, and that `READ_BUFFER_SIZE` is large enough to handle the data you are receiving.

And, we can rule out `bind()`, per Microsoft's [TCP/IP raw sockets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/tcp-ip-raw-sockets-2) documentation:

> On Windows 7, Windows Vista, Windows XP with Service Pack 2 (SP2), and Windows XP with Service Pack 3 (SP3), the ability to send traffic over raw sockets has been restricted in several ways:
>
> ...
>
> - **A call to the [bind](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winsock/nf-winsock-bind) function with a raw socket for the IPPROTO_TCP protocol is not allowed.**
>
>   Note
>   The `bind` function with a raw socket is allowed for other protocols (IPPROTO_IP, IPPROTO_UDP, or IPPROTO_SCTP, for example).

So, what does that leave? `recvfrom()` is complaining about an invalid parameter, and the only unknown parameter in this code is the `fromlen` parameter, since the code you have posted is not showing what you are passing in for that parameter. `recvfrom()` takes 6 parameters, but the code provided is showing only 5 values being passed in. What are you passing in for the `fromlen` parameter? You *should be* passing in the address of your `saddr_size` variable.  Do note that you should be resetting that variable's value every time you call `recvfrom()`, but you are only setting its value when you first declare it.

In any case, knowing that Microsoft imposes various restrictions on using TCP with RAW sockets, you should consider using `IPPROTO_RAW` or `IPPROTO_IP` instead, and then just filter out any non-TCP traffic you are not interested in.

---

On a side note: you should not be calling `closesocket()` after `WSACleanup()`, you have those two calls reversed. And, you are not calling `WSACleanup()` if `socket()` fails. This code should not be calling `WSAStartup()`/`WSACleanup()` to begin with, they belong at program startup/shutdown only, such as in your `main()`/`WinMain()` function.

Comment: Thank you, yes you have written everything correctly. 

And a question, to use IPPROTO_RAW or IPPROTO_IP, as I understand you need to bind via bind?  And the packet is filtered by checking protocol in IP header?  Thanks a lot.